# setVisibility is making multiple views dissapear

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm attempting to create two views and be able to toggle the visibility of one of them. The problem is that when I try to make one of the views invisible using set visibility, it affects both of them. Would anyone have any idea why this would be and how I can handle this situation better?

```
public AlarmDropDownForm(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();


}


View alarmBody;
View alarmHeader;

private void init() {
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    alarmHeadereader = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_form_header, this);
    alarmBody= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_form_layout, this);
    alarmBody.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

The XML for the files is as follows

alarm header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/help_title_gest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggle_contents"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/alarm_set_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Set Alarm"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BACammt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:onClick="toggle_contents"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

alarm body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/help_title_gest">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bacRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hidden_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="BAC:"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/BACspinner1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sendTextRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bacRow"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/send_text_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="send text:"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/alertContactsRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sendTextRow"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alert_contacts_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="alert contacts:"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post tour xml

Comment: @MoubeenFarooqWarar I've posted the XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alarmBody.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
`GONE` attribute hides not only view but also container

**Edit**

combine the two views

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/help_title_gest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggle_contents"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/alarm_set_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Set Alarm"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BACammt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:onClick="toggle_contents"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hiddenView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/help_title_gest">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bacRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hidden_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="BAC:"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/BACspinner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sendTextRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bacRow"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send_text_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="send text:"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alertContactsRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sendTextRow"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alert_contacts_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="alert contacts:"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

then in the code to find your content and hide it

```
private void init() {
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    alarmHeadereader = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_form_header, this);
    alarmBody= alarmHeadereader.findViewById(R.id.hiddenView);
    alarmBody.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Unfortunately I still seem to be getting the same issue with INVISIBLE. do you have any idea why this would be? I've included the XML if that helps.

Comment: Describe specifically what you want to get in the end

Comment: So essentially my hope is to have an expanding form. The header contains a "create alarm here" text, which when pressed will expand out into the "create alarm" form. clicking the header again will cause the form to contract.

Comment: Also, the reason I'm doing this by XML is that I want to be able to do it multiple times, and it would much easier/ much cleaner code wise if I could have these components as individual XML files.

Comment: Thank you that worked! I put them together and then identified the containers by id rather then the views as a whole. I still would like to know why that was happening though....

Comment: because they are in separate containers